# How to create a global variable with DI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to attempt something and I hope it is possible. I want a global property, containing the site base URL, that I can use across my application dlls. Here is what I thought of so far, while configuring my Dependency Injection:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddOrderEasyDependencies(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
   // Set golbal properties and configurations 
   var xxx = services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
   RunningConfig runningConfig = new(xxx);
   services.AddSingleton<IRunningConfig>(runningConfig);
}
```

Then the RunningConfig looks like this:

```
public class RunningConfig: IRunningConfig
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   public string SiteUrl { 
      get
      {
         var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
         var url = httpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + httpContext.Request.Host.Value;
         return url;
      }
   }

   public RunningConfig(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
   }
}
```

IRunningConfig is just an interface with a property.

I have `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in my ConfigureServices method in the startup class.

My problem is that IHttpContextAccessor is always null no matter how I do my injection. Please tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest a better way to do something like this.

I call the IRunningConfig like this:

```
public class SomeService: IService
{
    private readonly IRunningConfig _runningConfig;
    
    public SomeService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
       _runningConfig = services.GetService<IRunningConfig>();
    }
    
    public void DoMethodStuff()
    { 
       var urlAddress = _runningConfig.SiteUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you simply inject IHttpContextAccessor instead of the serviceCollection?

Comment: I tried to do this  
           var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
           var fooService = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
           RunningConfig runningConfig = new(fooService);  But no luck IHttpContextAccessor is still null

Comment: I meant doing `public RunningConfig(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)`

Comment: I still keep getting null.

Comment: DoMethodStuff is called in the context where a HttpContext is available? When a Request is actually going on?

Comment: I figured out that the HTTPContext is not available from where I was calling it. I am stuck now, again.

Comment: Request.Host is a client side value. The address used by the specific request by a specific client. There is no "the one url" for your service that you could read from somewhere in your system independent of a request. You might tell why you need that?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `services.BuildServiceProvider()`? Every time you are building new Provider and `Singleton` is not realy `Singleton` any more. You have to use DI

I would do it like this

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddOrderEasyDependencies(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
   // Set golbal properties and configurations 
   services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
// For IHttpContextAccessor registration there is an extention mehod in  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
// services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   services.AddSingleton<IRunningConfig, RunningConfig>();
}

public class RunningConfig: IRunningConfig
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   public string SiteUrl { 
      get
      {
         var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
         var url = httpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + httpContext.Request.Host.Value;
         return url;
      }
   }

   public RunningConfig(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, my httpContextAccessor is still null.

Comment: Is `IHttpContextAccessor` null or `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` and where are you getting null? On request or on startup?

Comment: HttpContext and on request

Comment: Okay, so the `Accessor` is not null. Can you post the code where are you try to get the `SiteUrl`

Comment: are you using `BuildServiceProvider()` some where else? You should not use it at all (for ASP projects). Framework builds the provider. `Provider` is like container for services with lifetime management. If you create the new one by calling `BuildServiceProvider` then you create new container with separate lifetime management

Comment: I edited my post to include how I am trying to access the RunningConfig class

Comment: I only use BuildServiceProvider on that one place

Comment: And `SomeService` is used in come `Controller`? What you are getting, if you inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into the `Controller` directly? `public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244897/discussion-between-demetrius-axenowski-and-spmoolman).

Comment: It is not coming from a controller. Where on startup will I be able to get access to the HTTPContext, to set the variable in this class? This call is made from a hangfire job and I need the sites url.